# Error in grails command object

Tags: grails

The strange part about this error is sometimes the page generates the error, and sometimes it doesn't.  I can't figure out what causes it or why:

```
errors.GrailsExceptionResolver ClassCastException occurred when processing request: [GET] /birthFamily/aboutYouLifestyle
java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to groovy.lang.Closure. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to groovy.lang.Closure
    at com.nrfa.LifestyleCommand$__clinit__closure1.doCall(Wizard.groovy:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

The offending command object:

```
@Validateable
public  class LifestyleCommand {
    Integer applicantNumber;
    Smoke smoke
    Drink drink
    Occupation occupation
    Set <String> hobby
    String occupationDetails

    static constraints = {
        importFrom Applicant, include:["smoke", "drink", "occupation", "occupationDetails", "applicantNumber"]
    }
}
```

Line 302 in the stack trace is the 'importFrom Applicant' line in the command object constraints.  What does 'java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to groovy.lang.Closure' indicate?

When I replace the constraints as a copy of those found in the Applicant domain, it also works fine:

```
static constraints = {

    applicantNumber (blank:false, nullable:false, range:1..2)
    smoke (blank:true, nullable:true)
    drink (blank:true, nullable:true)
    occupation (blank:true, nullable:true)
    occupationDetails (blank:true, nullable:true, maxSize:150)
}
```

EDIT:

Here is the relevant portion of the Applicant, which is a domain object:

```
class Applicant {

    static hasMany = [hobby:Hobby, ethnicity:Ethnicity]

    Integer applicantNumber
    String gender
    Integer yearBorn
    EyeColor eyeColor
    HairColor hairColor
    Integer heightFeet
    Integer heightInches

    static constraints = {
        applicantNumber (blank:false, nullable:false, range:1..2)
        gender (blank:true, nullable:true, validator: { value ->
            if (value != null && value != '' && (value != "M" && value != "F")) {
                return 'applicant.invalid.gender'
            }
        })
        yearBorn (blank:true, nullable:true, validator: { value ->
            if (value != null && (value < 1920 || value > 2014)) {
                return 'applicant.invalid.yearBorn'
            }
        })
        eyeColor (blank:true, nullable:true)
        hairColor (blank:true, nullable:true)
        smoke (blank:true, nullable:true)
        drink (blank:true, nullable:true)
        heightFeet (blank:true, nullable:true, validator: { value ->
            if (value != null && (value < 3 || value > 7)) {
                return 'applicant.invalid.heightFeet'
            }
        })
        heightInches (blank:true, nullable:true, validator: { value ->
            if (value != null && (value < 1 || value > 12)) {
                return 'applicant.invalid.heightInches'
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Wizard is my controller.  There is an action to process a form request which submits the data to be populated into the LifestyleCommand object.  I'm just submitting the page back with none of the fields filled out, so everything is null/empty which is valid.

I'm running grails 2.2.4

Comment: Can you also post `Applicant` as is, in the question?

Comment: And what is `Wizard.groovy`?

Comment: It looks like it's trying to cast the "include" section of the importFrom as a "last-argument" closure.  However, this doesn't make sense, as importFrom has taken an include list argument since it was added to 2.0.2 (according to the docs) http://grails.org/doc/2.0.2/guide/validation.html#constraints  I'd like to see what params exist for this binding, and what version of Grails is in use.

Comment: I've added the applicant domain and provided an explanation on the wizard code.

Comment: Don't you have `occupation` and `occupationDetails` and their constraints in `Applicant`?

Comment: I think it is a problem in grails itself, but I don't have time to build a little test app to prove it.  My controller extended a base controller, and the command objects were in the base controller, both as inner classes and in the file itself, just to test both.  When I removed the extension and put the command objects back in my main controller, errors stopped occurring.

Answer (score 2):

As was pointed out in the comments you probably should remove `occupation` and `occupationDetails` from `include` block of `LifestyleCommand` constraints (there are no constaints of that fields in `Applicant`).